# Semi-colon vs comma usage in long list

Tags: punctuation, semicolons

I have doubt on semicolon and comma usage, should I swap their positions? Or should I put colon instead of semicolon?

> Out of the major expenses incurred by the company, raw materials accounted for 46 percent of the total income, employee cost; nine percent, power and fuel; two percent, advertisement; one percent, interest; four percent, depreciation; four percent, tax; two percent, dividend; two percent and other expenses 20 percent.

I have a doubt about the way semicolon is used, for example:

> employee cost; nine percent

I have used a 'comma' after nine percent and before 'power and fuel'. I have separated 'employee cost' 'power and fuel cost' and 'advertisement' cost with comma – am I correct in separating the content by comma and using the semicolon for depicting the percentage?

Comment: The text is full of commas and colons. Will you please be more specific about what you need? About what you do not understand?

Comment: Unless you can give a *specific* example of punctuation usage that is of concern, this is akin to asking for us to proofread and rewrite your sentence (which is off topic).

Answer (score 1):

I did not read the sentence carefully enough from the beginning, sorry.

Comma is used when separating elements of the same statement.

The semicolon is used instead of a full stop, when total separation is not desired.

Therefore, in your case, you should switch the uses of commas and semicolons.

---

The statements should be:

> (Out of the major expenses incurred by the company,)
>
> raw materials accounted for 46 percent of the total income,
>
> employee cost; nine percent,
>
> power and fuel; two percent,
>
> advertisement; one percent,
>
> interest; four percent,
>
> depreciation; four percent,
>
> tax; two percent,
>
> dividend; two percent
>
> and other expenses 20 percent.

Therefore, it is obvious that the usage is not correct. You ended statements with a comma instead of a semicolon, and you joined elements inside the statement with a semicolon instead of a comma.

Please note that the first comma (inside the bracketed first line) is used properly.

Comment: But, the edited sentence is similar to the my original sentence. for eg., your sentence reads - employee cost; nine percent, power and fuel; two percent,

Comment: The edited sentence is **exactly** your sentence. I just wanted to help you see why the commas and the semicolons should be used in the opposite way.